# Can't Open File [Errno 2 ] No such file or directory

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, vscode-code-runner

I am new to coding and trying to run a python code in VS Code using code runner but it doesn't work, I think the issue is that code runner runs C:/c/--------
which doesn't exist in my directory, but I don't know how to go about solving it.
[screenshot of terminal when I try to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCvV8.png)

Code in terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\Kevin> python -u "/c/Users/Kevin/Desktop/Coding/Python/testing/hello.py"

C:\Python\Python39\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\c\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Coding\Python\testing\hello.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Seems that the extra "/c" is not needed since it is already getting appended to the absolute path provided. Please check whether the path provided is correct.

Comment: Please copy/paste the terminal output into a code block instead of posting a screenshot. This makes the post more accessible and easier to read.

Comment: the path I provided is the screenshot of when I run using code-runner I don't really know how to remove the extra /c appended to it

Comment: btw you can run python code without the coderunner extension, just disable it and you should be able to run the code

Answer (score 0):

How do you run your python file with `Code Runner`?

Normally, it should be like this:

[image]

I can't reproduce code runner automatically taken a path that starts with `/` or `\`. And the path took `slash` instead of `backslash` as the path separator.

Do you click here to run the python file?

[image]

Comment: I right-click and press run code but using the button at the top right produces the same error. It works when I use the second option in the drop-down menu (run python file in terminal) which is weird bc they both run in terminal (windows Powershell)

Comment: @failing Yes, both `run code` and click the button at the top right were taking `Code Runner` to run the code, it has the same problem. Could you try to reinstall the `Code Runner` extension?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately after reinstallation the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. go to code runner settings, `@ext:formulahendry.code-runner`
2. open the Code runner: Executor map
3. edit in Json
4. change `code-runner.terminalRoot` value to `""`
5. go back to settings and unmark the Run in Terminal box